# Sequel can't connect to MySQL using login parameters provided by ARGV through .cmd, but works fine from command line

Tags: mysql, ruby, cmd, argv, sequel

`init.rb`:

```
## LOCAL DB
DB = Sequel.connect(
    :adapter => 'mysql',
    :user => ARGV[1],
    :password => ARGV[2],
    :host => '127.0.0.1',
    :database => ARGV[3]
)
```

`A.cmd`:

```
ruby init.rb A 'root' 'MY_PASSWORD' 'DATABASE_NAME'
```

When I double click `A.cmd`, it opens and crashes, spitting out this error:

`Mysql::Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

But when I open a command prompt, type `A.cmd` and run it, the script works fine.

Why?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is possible administration rights. Right click on `A.cmd` and select "run as administrator" and see if that does any different.

Comment: @Micah Nope, no change. But my password does have an `&` in it, which seems to throw off the script. When I removed it, the `.cmd` ran fine, but why does the `&` mess everything up?

Comment: Most likely due to the fact that `&` are special characters in windows command prompts used to separate commands. Not sure why the `&` worked when you manually typed it in unless you used a different quotation or some other trigger that told the console to ignore it.

Comment: @Micah I didn't use any special characters. I typed it in the same way it's written in the .cmd file.